# How to do interpolation in MYSQL with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database and I need an interpolation funtion to create a report. The top tables look like:

Table 1

```
+--+--------+-------+-----+
|ID| Acreage| Fvalue| Type|
+--+--------+-------+-----+
| 1|   16.24|   null|    1|
| 2|    2.17|   null|    1|
| 3|  138.00|   null|    3|
| 4|  138.00|   null|    1|
| 5|  142.47|   null|    3|
| 6|    6.16|   null|    2|
| 7|   14.80|   null|    2|
| 8|   26.01|   null|    1|
| 9|   26.01|   null|    3|
|10|    1.45|   null|    3|
+--+--------+-------+-----+
```

Table 2

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Acreage| Factor| Type|
+--------+-------+-----+
|       0|   3.35|    1|
|       1|   3.35|    1|
|       3|    2.3|    1|
|       5|   1.92|    1|
|      10|   1.42|    1|
|      15|    1.2|    1|
|      20|      1|    1|
|     999|      1|    1|
|       0|   2.22|    2|
|       1|   2.22|    2|
|       3|   1.97|    2|
|       5|   1.76|    2|
|      10|   1.55|    2|
|      15|   1.32|    2|
|      20|   1.07|    2|
|      22|      1|    2|
|     999|      1|    2|
|       0|   6.93|    3|
|       1|   6.93|    3|
|       3|   5.39|    3|
|       5|   4.05|    3|
|      10|   2.51|    3|
|      15|   2.08|    3|
|      20|   1.69|    3|
|      25|   1.31|    3|
|      30|      1|    3|
|     999|      1|    3|
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I need to check each Acreage in table 1 on the Acreage in table 2 but the Types have to match as well. If the Acreage is between values I have to use a function that uses the closest value below and above, pull the average between the two numbers, and always round up.

I took inspiration from this post [How to do an interpolation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492251/how-to-do-an-interpolation-in-mysql)
but I can't quite get it right. I'm not sure how to join the two tables in the calculations since I have decimal values in my table 1 Acreage column.

I created a demo using SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed60a9/1

It should look something like this when correct

````
+--+--------+-------+-----+
|ID| Acreage| Fvalue| Type|
+--+--------+-------+-----+
| 1|   16.24|  1.151|    1|
| 2|    2.17|  2.736|    1|
| 3|  138.00|      1|    3|
| 4|  138.00|      1|    1|
| 5|  142.47|      1|    3|
| 6|    6.16|  1.712|    2|
| 7|   14.80|  1.330|    2|
| 8|   26.01|      1|    1|
| 9|   26.01|  1.248|    3|
|10|    1.45|  6.584|    3|
+--+--------+-------+-----+


Edit*

I ended up getting this to work, so I'm building around it instead.


```drop table if exists t1;
````

```
insert into t1 values
(1,16.24,null,1),
(2,2.17,null,1),
(3,138.00,null,3),
(4,138.00,null,1),
(5,142.47,null,3),
(6,6.16,null,2),
(7,14.80,null,2),
(8,26.01,null,1),
(9,26.01,null,3),
(10,1.45,null,3)
;
```

```
insert into example values
(0,3.35,1),
(1,3.35,1),
(3,2.3,1),
(5,1.92,1),
(10,1.42,1),
(15,1.2,1),
(20,1,1),
(999,1,1),
(0,2.22,2),
(1,2.22,2),
(3,1.97,2),
(5,1.76,2),
(10,1.55,2),
(15,1.32,2),
(20,1.07,2),
(22,1,2),
(999,1,2),
(0,6.93,3),
(1,6.93,3),
(3,5.39,3),
(5,4.05,3),
(10,2.51,3),
(15,2.08,3),
(20,1.69,3),
(25,1.31,3),
(30,1,3),
(999,1,3);
```

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      s.Acreage Acreage1,
      s.Factor Factor1,
      s1.Acreage Acreage2,
      s1.Factor Factor2,
      s1.Type Type1,
      s.Type Type2
  FROM
      example s
  LEFT JOIN example s1 ON (s.Acreage < s1.Acreage)  and s.Type = s1.Type
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM example as s2
    WHERE s.Acreage < s2.Acreage
    AND
        s2.Acreage < s1.Acreage
    )
  OR s1.Acreage IS NULL
) t
ON
    t1.Acreage >= t.Acreage1 AND t1.Acreage < t.Acreage2  and t1.Type = t.Type1
SET Fvalue =         
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.Acreage = t.Acreage1 THEN t.Factor1 
        WHEN (t1.Acreage > t.Acreage1 AND t1.Acreage < t.Acreage2) THEN
           (t.Factor1 + ((t1.Acreage - t.Acreage1)/(t.Acreage2-t.Acreage1))*(t.Factor2 - t.Factor1))
        ELSE NULL 
    END;
```

My updated Fiddle example can be found here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/477c1c

New testing tables

```
create table table1 (ID int, Acreage decimal(10,2), Fvalue decimal(8, 4), Type int);
insert into table1 values
(1,0.75,null,6),
(2,0.42,null,6),
(3,0.66,null,6),
(4,0.62,null,6),
(5,0.51,null,6),
(6,0.46,null,6),
(7,0.66,null,6),
(8,0.72,null,6),
(9,0.5,null,6),
(10,0.05,null,6)

;
```

```
create table table2 (Acreage int, Factor decimal(8, 4), Type int);
insert into table2 values
(999,1,6),
(1,1,6),
(0.9,0.95,6),
(0.8,0.9,6),
(0.7,0.85,6),
(0.6,0.8,6),
(0.5,0.75,6),
(0.4,0.7,6),
(0.3,0.65,6),
(0.2,0.6,6),
(0.1,0.6,6)

;
```

Edit 2* Solved.

I overlooked the fact that I created my table2 Acreage column using Int, and the reason it wasn't working on values lower than 1 was because....they were being changed in the table to 1.

Comment: interpolation... inspiration.... -->> `JOIN` and `UNION`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: So, for ID 1 in Table 1, you would have to get the average of the calculation of your function using 15 and 20 of type 1 (Table 2), and use that as Fvalue of Table 1, right?

Comment: Not quite. it's not the average I need but an interpolated value. For ID 2, the average value between acreage 1 and acreage 3 in table 2 is 2.825, while the interpolated value should be 2.736.

Comment: This can be easily done with lateral joins, available in MySQL 8.0.14. However, you fiddle seems to be using MySQL 5.6. Can you clarify which version are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using mysql 6.3. My solution I posted works on all but 1 of my types. I have a type 6 (that I didn't include in the original post) that usually only factors acreage < 1.0. I don't understand why, but I am not getting the correct Fvalue. The Fvalue I am getting is too high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0.14 or newer you can use lateral queries to find the border rows. Then interpolation is trivial.

For example:

```
select 
  a.id,
  a.acreage,
  case when lo.type is not null and hi.type is not null
       then lo.factor + (a.acreage - lo.acreage)
                      / (hi.acreage - lo.acreage)
                      * (hi.factor - lo.factor)
  end as fvalue,
  a.type
from table1 a,
lateral (
  select *
  from table2 b
  where b.type = a.type and b.acreage <= a.acreage
  order by b.acreage desc
  limit 1
) lo,
lateral (
  select *
  from table2 b
  where b.type = a.type and b.acreage > a.acreage
  order by b.acreage
  limit 1
) hi
```

Result:

```
 id  acreage  fvalue        type 
 --- -------- ------------- ---- 
 1   16.24    1.1504000000  1    
 2   2.17     2.7357500000  1    
 3   138.00   1.0000000000  3    
 4   138.00   1.0000000000  1    
 5   142.47   1.0000000000  3    
 6   6.16     1.7112800000  2    
 7   14.80    1.3292000000  2    
 8   26.01    1.0000000000  1    
 9   26.01    1.2473800000  3    
 10  1.45     6.5835000000  3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=092b3a66a74f5d095d8f51ed9a037835).

If you want to update the table you can combine the query above into an `UPDATE` statement, as in:

```
update table1 y
join (
select 
  a.id,
  case when lo.type is not null and hi.type is not null
       then lo.factor + (a.acreage - lo.acreage)
                      / (hi.acreage - lo.acreage)
                      * (hi.factor - lo.factor)
  end as fvalue
from table1 a,
lateral (
  select *
  from table2 b
  where b.type = a.type and b.acreage <= a.acreage
  order by b.acreage desc
  limit 1
) lo,
lateral (
  select *
  from table2 b
  where b.type = a.type and b.acreage > a.acreage
  order by b.acreage
  limit 1
) hi
) x on x.id = y.id
set y.fvalue = x.fvalue
```

See [Update fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b838531ef961a176e71fc52c78ff31cb).

Comment: I've updated your example with the type that is giving me issues, and I can't get it to run correctly with your example either. I've added the new tables at the bottom of my question

Comment: Your answer is the easiest if I was using a version of mysql that uses lateral queries. For anyone that also can't use lateral queries my solution will work.